# Regex match exact number of a specific character

Tags: r, regex, string

Let's say I want to find all words in which letter "e" appears exactly two times. When I define this pattern:

```
pattern1 <- "e.*e" 
grep(pattern1, stringr::words, value = T)
```

RegEx also matches words such as "therefore", because "e" appears (at least) two times as well. The point is, I don't want my pattern to be "at least", I want it to be "exactly n times".

This pattern...

```
  pattern2 <- "e{2}"
```

...finds words with two letter "e", but only if they appear one after each other ("feel", "agre" etc). I'd like to combines these two patterns to find all words with exact number of not necessarily consecutive appearances of a letter "e".

Comment: Please [check my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46928466/3832970) for an easily scalable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
^(?:[^e]*e){2}[^e]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DyP5e7/1). The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that allows quantifying a *sequence* of subpatterns and is thus easily adjustable to match 3, 4 or more specific sequences in a string.

**Details**

- `^`- start of string
- `(?:[^e]*e){2}` - 2 occurrences of

  - `[^e]*` - any 0+ chars other than `e`
  - `e` - an `e`
- `[^e]*` - any 0+ chars other than `e`
- `$` - end of string

See the [R demo below](https://ideone.com/MuxhFx):

```
x <- c("feel", "agre", "degree")
rx <- "^(?:[^e]*e){2}[^e]*$"
grep(rx, x, value = TRUE)
## => [1] "feel"
```

Note that instead of `value = T` it is safer to use `value = TRUE` as `T` might be redefined in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a pattern to match zero or more characters that are not 'e' (`[^e]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by character 'e', then another set of characters that are not 'e' followed by 'e', and zero or more characters not an 'e' until the end (`$`) of the string

```
res <- grep("^[^e]*e[^e]*e[^e]*$", stringr::words, value = TRUE)
stringr::str_count(res, "e")
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#[58] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#[115] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also explain to me shortly how in detail this pattern works?

Answer (score 1):

^[^e]*e[^e]*e[^e]*$

^ asserts :: start of the string

[^e]*  :: Match a zero or more character not present in the list

*(asterisk) — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

e  :: matches the character e literally (case sensitive)

repeat [^e]*  to match all other characters if between 2 e's

$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

so, [^e]* matches all characters except e, zero or multiple times. so that if string contain only e then also condition satisfy as it consider zero occurrence of all other characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay *not* using `grep`

```
stringr::str_count(words, "e") == 2
```

If you want more efficiency,

```
stringi::stri_count_fixed(words, "e") == 2
```

Both of these return logical vectors, you can get the words with `words[..code from above..]`