# How to find all the words that have a letter appears TWICE in them with Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm learning how to use regular expression with Python. I came across a question about finding words that contains a certain frequency of a letter in a word.

Given a list of words, for example, `['elle','household','lel','bye']`, I want to use regular expression find words that have exactly 2 'l's regardless of the position of the letter. 
So for this example, the return list should be `['elle','lel']`

Comment: And what have you tried? :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match exact number of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928343/regex-match-exact-number-of-letters)

Comment: I managed to solve it but it feels inefficient.First, I select words that have one or more 'l'. Then use for loop, break it into a list of characters, then calculate the 'l' that appears. If the frequency equals 2 , then put into a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Really, use a `Counter` here instead:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['elle','household','lel','bye']

double_l = [word
            for word in lst
            for c in [Counter(word)]
            if c['l'] == 2]

print(double_l)
# ['elle', 'lel']
```

---

If you insist (why?), this is how you "count" with regular expressions:

```
^(?:[^l]*l){2}[^l]*$
```

That shiny piece of code says:

```
^             # bound the expression to the start
(?:[^l]*l){2} # not an l, followed by an l, two times
[^l]*         # no l thereafter
$             # the end
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xGHyYr/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex such as

```
^[^l]*l[^l]*l[^l]*$
```

This looks for exactly two `l` characters with zero or more other characters before, between and after. Additionally the `^` and `$` ensure that the match looks at all of the characters.

Comment: @Jan, you and I were writing at the same time. As there were no answers I wrote mine. After I pressed the submit I first saw yours. My regex is, I believe, simpler than yours and thus easier to understand.